# When installing ngrx/data with angular cli getting No provider for HttpClient error in console

Tags: angular, ngrx

Good morning,
I am trying to use ng add to my angular 8/9 applications for ngrx/data
no errors on compilation but on runtime i am getting a No provider for HttpClient error in console.
no such problems for effect, store and entity packages that are working.

when removing the line
    EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)
from the app module there is no error but no ngrx data.

thanks

Comment: please share working demo on stackblitz

Comment: Try this: provide DefaultDataServiceFactory.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
To resolve this problem HttpClient is Angular's mechanism for communicating with a remote server over HTTP.

To make HttpClient available everywhere in the app,

open the root AppModule,

import the HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http,

add it to the @NgModule.imports array.

Add the following to app.module.ts:

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
After that add in the import section like imports:[HttpClientModule,  ]
```